# Is there a design pattern that can help me store object "capabilities"?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working on a C# program that allows a user to interact with and configure various AV devices such as receivers and switchers over a TCP telnet style connection (according to the command sets of the various device manufacturers). I use the command pattern to encapsulate the commands. The app can only interact with one device at a time, so when it connects it enumerates the device and creates a DeviceVersion object. This object stores certain properties that are common to all the devices. It also needs to maintain a list of capabilities for each device. For instance some devices do not have volume control. Others do, but don't have the ability to change input devices. I hate the idea of storing a long list of booleans inside each DeviceVersion object. I think I should have something like a CapabilityContract object that encapsulates a dictionary such as Dictionary which can map capability names to booleans. At least that way I can put in a ContractFactory or something that can generate those capability objects on the fly, either through text config files or some other method.

However, when it comes to parsing command output, in some cases the capabilities allowed may change how a response is parsed. For instance an AV switch that can separate audio and video on an output may have a GetInput command which returns an ordered pair like (audio input, video input), however, on a device where audio and video are always linked it may just return (input). The command parser interface implementation maintains a reference back to the DeviceVersion, so it can look up the capabilities but that leads to quite a few if statements, or switch statements. I toyed with the idea of generating a different parser implementation for each DeviceVersion type, but that will lead to a lot of duplicated code. Is there some design pattern I am missing that can simplify this problem for me and avoid a lot of either maintaining boolean values, or lots of duplicate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was to approach this problem I would go with a [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), also on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), where I defined a Base Interface (no implementation) or Abstract class (contains some implementation) and then a Factory to retrieve these objects.

This way you have a common implementation for your system to communicate with these Devices and you aren't duplicating code because you are just inheriting the base class to create implementations for each device you may interface with. I'd suggest that you make your DeviceVersion object a little more generic and turn that into the base class. You can wrap up your command pattern implementation into the Factory Pattern and that should help you get there.

I used this pattern a while back to implement a C# application that would allow you to switch between four different types of DVRs using four different SDKs.

This is a quick and dirty example:

DeviceType Enum:

```
public enum DeviceType {
  Receiver,
  Switcher
  // etc
}
```

Base Class:

```
public interface DeviceVersion {
  // What type is this?
  DeviceType DeviceType { get; }

  // Common Properties and Methods, etc here
  #region Function Availability Properties

  bool CanFastForward { get; }
  bool CanPlay { get; }
  bool CanStop { get; }
  bool Can... { get; }
  ...

  #endregion

  #region Methods

  bool Connect(string ipAddress, string user, string password);
  void Disconnect();
  void Play();
  void Stop();
  ...

  #endregion
}
```

Switcher Class:

```
public class Switcher : DeviceVersion {
  // Override the virtual
  public DeviceType DeviceType { get { return DeviceType.Switcher; } }

  public bool CanPlay
  {
      get { return true; }
  }
  ...
}
```

Factory Class:

```
public class DeviceFactory {
  // This is the factory method
  public static DeviceVersion GetDevice(DeviceType type) {
    switch (type) {
      case DeviceType.Switcher:
        return new Switcher();
      case DeviceType.Receiver:
        ...
      default:
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your main methods when you are connecting to a different device you'd go:

```
...
var currentDeviceType = DeviceTypes.Switcher;
...
var device = DeviceFactory.GetDevice(currentDeviceType);
if (device.Connect("1.2.3.4", "user", "pass")) {
  if (device.CanPlay)
    device.Play();
  ...
}
...
```

As for the contracts and capabilities you could implement a dictionary or similar in the base class to hold those items as everything in the base class is inherited by the classes that inherit from it.

Comment: The crux of this is that two Switcher's may have different feature sets. They are more like components, so overriding a base class gets pretty messy as there will be a ton of duplicate code in each class as they check for different features. I'd like to build my feature list and then apply it to a DeviceVersion (already created by a factory method). The problem I am running in to is that the response parser and command queue must enforce the feature list and I want to avoid a ton of if's or switch statements.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a tough nut to crack. I added some clarification to my example for how I handled the different "capabilities" of the different DVRs I had interfaced with. None of the SDKs I was working with did anything the same way. Trying to deal with this disparate features set might also be solved by looking at [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and seeing if there is a way you wrap what you are trying to do into an extensible class structure.

Comment: Maybe I could make my CommandQueue and ResponseParser objects a sort of Entity Component pattern, where the actual parse and execute functions are themselves components. But this just moves all the checking of feature sets into a factory, it doesn't get rid of them. Still, maybe that is preferable to checking them every time a command is executed? (Though I am not concerned with CPU or memory optimization here as everything is pretty lightweight) I just feel like I saw a problem like this solved by some patterns, but I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but it may be worth taking a look at the [Facade](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-facade-pattern--cms-22238) and [Adapter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-adapter-pattern--cms-22262) patterns as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is the aim of DeviceVersion class, maybe DeviceInfo describes it better. My suggestion is to use IDeviceCapability collection where each item represent one capability such as IPlayable. This way you can attach/detach, get info, enable/disable and do other things with all capabilities but with only one implementation for all specific capabilities. Though you can override them anyway.

Another good thing about this is that you can test and mock each capability separately of DeviceInfo class. Changes in DeviceCapability doesn't affect DeviceInfo and all DeviceCapability implementations.